# Replace underscore from all html href with regex and python

Tags: python, regex

So I'm currently using python.

How can I go through a HTML file and replace all occurrences of:

`<a href="#some_snake_case_text">`

and transform it into:

`<a href="#somesnakecasetext">`

independent of the text there is inside the the **href**?

So I was going for Regex, I'm now a couple of hours in and I didn't succeed in matching the "_" in-between the **href** tag in order to remove them... I cannot just match the word and do a replace all cus that would actually replace all those through the entire document which is not intended.

I tried this to math all the "_"

`<a href=\"#(.*(_).*)+\">`

or everything but the underscores:

`<a href=\"#([^_]_?)+\">`

to then maybe replace it?!

How can I do this?

Comment: Kindly please also upvote helpful answers below, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a method in replacement:

```py
import re

def subst(x):
    return x.group().replace('_', '')

s = 'xxx <a href="#some_snake_case_text"> xxx'
p = r'<a\s+href="#[^"]*">'
print(re.sub(p, subst, s))
```

See [Python proof.](https://tio.run/##LY7LDsIgEEX3fMUEFwPadOPOtP0RHwTr1DZaIANN8OuRRO/mLO5ZnPBJs3fHUpY1eE7AJMSDJojbPSaV9UlAHVPa2EFun@y3oHTLFN52JIUGG0DUQkToAXPO0FmYmaZe7qJfyURnX2RGG8kkykkOUCUUoeqMnb3Ew98@3@R1L4d68eKSYmprgwrNL6VCa1HKFw)

**Results**: `xxx <a href="#somesnakecasetext"> xxx`

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  <a                       '<a'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  href="#                  'href="#'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ">                       '">'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.sub`:

```
import re
s = '<a href="#some_snake_case_text">'
new_s = re.sub('(?<=href\=")[^"]+', lambda x:''.join(x.group().split('_')), s)
```

Output:

```
'<a href="#somesnakecasetext">'
```